# Add static page in JHipster

Tags: java, angular, jhipster

I'd like to add what amounts to a static HTML page into my JHipster app. The body of the page will be static (a privacy policy), but I want it to use the same navbar as other pages so they all have the same look and feel and can navigate seamlessly between other pages.

I tried creating a new angular `component` using angular CLI:

```
> ng generate component privacy-policy

CREATE src/main/webapp/app/privacy-policy/privacy-policy.component.html (33 bytes)
CREATE src/main/webapp/app/privacy-policy/privacy-policy.component.ts (265 bytes)
UPDATE src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ts (2879 bytes)
```

I'm confused on how to configure routing for this so that `/privacy-policy` resolves to this new component.  I tried creating a new router for this component as follows but it didn't work:

```
import { Route } from '@angular/router';

import {PrivacyPolicyComponent} from 'app/privacy-policy/privacy-policy.component';

export const privacyPolicyRoute: Route = {
    path: 'privacy-policy',
    component: PrivacyPolicyComponent,
    outlet: 'privacy-policy'
};
```

I also tried updating the generated `app-routing.module.ts` file to include the new component but that also didn't work:

```
import {privacyPolicyRoute} from 'app/privacy-policy/privacy-policy.route';
...
const LAYOUT_ROUTES = [privacyPolicyRoute, navbarRoute, ...errorRoute];
```

No matter what I get the following browser error:

```
Router Event: NavigationError platform-browser.js:216
    NavigationError(id: 2, url: '/privacy-policy', error: Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'privacy-policy') platform-browser.js:211
    Object { id: 2, url: "/privacy-policy", error: Error }
```

How can I get my app to properly route requests to my new component?

Comment: This older question solved my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46587247/adding-new-route-to-jhipster-using-angular-4

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need `outlet: 'privacy-policy'` ? Remove it. You're probably trying to place the component into an outlet which doesn't exist.

Comment: I was just re-using some code from another router. I removed the `outlet` attribute but now when I navigate to `/#/privacy-policy` I see the same browser error and it redirects me to one of my entity URLs. Progress I suppose :)

Comment: It should work. Restart your app. Also make sure PrivacyPolicyComponent is declared in AppModule.

Comment: The angular CLI added `import { PrivacyPolicyComponent } from './privacy-policy/privacy-policy.component';` to AppModule. I stopped the Java and npm processes, did a full maven clean and webpack build, and I'm still having the same problem.

Comment: This article, despite being Angular 4, solved my problem. Thanks for your time! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46587247/adding-new-route-to-jhipster-using-angular-4 (tl;dr I needed to create a PrivacyPolicyModule)

Comment: No worries. Although you don't really need to a new Module for a static page, just declaring it in your AppModule is enough :)